# How to update specific property by comparing two array of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below two array of object in javascript

```
data1 = [
  {
    id: 123,
    option: "ABC",
    value: "123"
  },
  {
    id: 234,
    option: "DFG",
    value: "234"
  }
];

data2 = [
  {
    id: 123,
    option: "ABC",
    value: "123"
  }
];
```

When the id is  match with 2nd array of object then i wanted to set the value(property) to 0 in first array of object for that particular id only. Like below once id 123 got match in both array then data1 array should look like this

```
data1 = [
  {
    id: 123,
    option: "ABC",
    value: "0"
  },
  {
    id: 234,
    option: "DFG",
    value: "234"
  }
];
```

How to achieve the above scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

You can save the ids of data2 in a `Set` and iterate over data1 and change the value of each item if its id is in the set:

```js
let data1 = [{ id: 123, option: 'ABC', value: "123" }, { id: 234, option: "DFG", value: "234" } ];
let data2 = [{ id: 123, option: 'ABC', value: "123" } ];
let set = new Set();
for(let i = 0; i < data2.length; i++)
     set.add(data2[i]['id'])
for(let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++)
     if(set.has(data1[i]['id']))
          data1[i]['value'] = 0;
console.log(data1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a set of all the object ids from the second array with a [`new Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), and then [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your first array to new objects, changing the `value` property if the object's id is within the set (checked using `.has()`):

```js
const data1 = [{ id: 123, option: 'ABC', value: "123" }, { id: 234, option: "DFG", value: "234" } ];
const data2 = [{ id: 123, option: 'ABC', value: "123" }];

const idSet = new Set(data2.map(o => o.id));
const res = data1.map(o => ({...o, value: idSet.has(o.id) ? "0" : o.value}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `foreach`, this will mutate your first array, which is what you need, or you can also make use of `map`(but it will generate new array):

```js
var data1 = [{ id: 123, option: 'ABC', value: "123" }, { id: 234, option: "DFG", value: "234" } ];
var data2 = [ { id: 123, option: 'ABC', value: "123" } ];

data1.forEach(k=>{
  ispresent = data2.find(p=>p.id==k.id);
  if(ispresent) k.value = '0'
});

console.log(data1);
```